# Is it possible to add a Shell Admin when the SP server is installed on the DC?

Tags: 2010, powershell

I know there are many reasons why a SharePoint 2010 Server should not be on a Domain Controller but this is for a test Server that was rolled up quickly.

The current problem is I need to run Powershell as a local administrator. Domain controllers can't have local users so I'm not sure how I can add a Shell admin.

Any suggestions or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Can't you run your PowerShell script as Administrator (of the server) and not SP_Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Add-SPShellAdmin should do the trick. Be sure to run the SharePoint management shell as an administrator if you have User Account Control activated.

Add-SPShellAdmin reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607596(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the Add-SPShellAdmin command won't work because it needs to be run under a local admin account

Comment: Normally that should also work on a domain controller. What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: **Add-SPShellAdmin : You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet.**

The problem being that I can't run the Powershell cmdlet with a machine account because it is a domain controller. This is run under the Share Point administration account.

Comment: Figured it out. Log in as admin (Run As won't work). Turn off UAC in **Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change User Account Control Settings**. Run Powershell as Admin and it should work fine now.

Comment: Okay, was ready to install an all-in-one box just to check if I was not getting crazy :) Glad it worked!